# How to measure performance of a web browser?

Tags: 11.04, performance, browser

I am curious to know which browser is the fastest one on my thinkpad x300 running Ubuntu 11.04. Could someone tell me how to measure performance of a browser on ubuntu 11.04, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use PeaceKeeper for that: http://clients.futuremark.com/peacekeeper/index.action

Answer (score 3):

Start-up time can be measured with a stop watch and a quick hand. The rest of the benchmarks are generally to do with JavaScript performance. Naturally a company will want to show their product is the best so you need to look carefully at the results.

[SunSpider](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider/sunspider.html) is a type of test that you could run. There are others. I don't know if SunSpider is in fashion or what the latest and greatest is but it will give you some indication.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested SunSpider on different browsers Firefox 4.0.1, Opera 11.11, Google Chrome, and Epiphany 2.30.6 running on Ubuntu 11.06. Firefox 4.0.1 significantly beats all other three -- 1.23 times faster. Opera and Chrome show same performance and Epiphony shows worst performance.